# Why I get an exception error on a database insert command?

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle, oledbconnection

```
public static string storeAvatar(string avatar, string gender, string species, int playerforeignkey )
{ 
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
        OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand();

        dbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AVATARS ([AVATAR_ID],[AVATAR],[DOB],[STRENGTH],[GENDER],[HOARD],[SPECIES], [METAMORPHOSED], [COST],[PLAYERID_FK]) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; // command to get high score data
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "AVATARS_SEQ.NEXTVAL");
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@avatar", avatar);
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", "TO_CHAR(" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")+")");
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strength", 0);
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hoard", 0);
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@species", species);
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meta", 0);
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", 0);
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@playerfk", playerforeignkey);
        dbCommand.Connection = myConnection;
        myConnection.Open();
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return "ERROR";
}
```

The exception error says I need miss a `SELECT` keyword, however I want `INSERT` not `SELECT`.

> EXCEPTION =  "One or more errors occurred during processing of
>   command.\r\nORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword"

Comment: Can you share exact exception message? The parameters in the query are mentioned as `?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?`, is it intentional? You need to use actual command names there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, update the command text to use the actual parameter names and second the purpose of using the parameters is also to avoid SQL injection which you try to do with your parameters.

There is no need for the @id parameter as that value can be placed directly into the string as will as the `TO_CHAR` function.

```
//..other code removed for brevity
dbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AVATARS ([AVATAR_ID],[AVATAR],[DOB],[STRENGTH],[GENDER],[HOARD],[SPECIES], [METAMORPHOSED], [COST],[PLAYERID_FK]) VALUES (AVATARS_SEQ.NEXTVAL,@avatar,TO_CHAR(@date),@strength,@gender,@hoard,@species,@meta,@cost,@playerfk)";
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@avatar", avatar);
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"));
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strength", 0);
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hoard", 0);
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@species", species);
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meta", 0);
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", 0);
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@playerfk", playerforeignkey);
//..other code removed for brevity
```

In fact I would even advise that all the constant values be placed directly into the query and reduce the parameters to only the ones expected to change frequently.

for example

```
//..other code removed for brevity
dbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AVATARS ([AVATAR_ID],[AVATAR],[DOB],[STRENGTH],[GENDER],[HOARD],[SPECIES], [METAMORPHOSED], [COST],[PLAYERID_FK]) 
VALUES (AVATARS_SEQ.NEXTVAL,@avatar,TO_CHAR(@date),0,@gender,0,@species,0,0,@playerfk)";
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@avatar", avatar);
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"));
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@species", species);
dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@playerfk", playerforeignkey);
//..other code removed for brevity
```